# Rails Migration: Adding comment to column without changing type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I'm currently working on a task to add a large number of comments to the columns in a database. I currently am approaching it trying to use the change_column function like the code below; however I'm running into some errors and worried I could accidentally change some types when I actually want to leave them alone.

```
change_column :tablename, :id, :bigint, comment: "id"
```

This results in the following error when the column in question is a foreign key.:

> Mysql2::Error: Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'fk_rails_(8 character series of numbers and letters)' of
>   table 'databasename.tablename'

I also tried the following approach,

```
change_column_comment :tablename, :id, comment:'ID'
```

it results in the following error:

> change_column_comment(:tablename, :id, {:comment=>"ID"})
>
> rails aborted! NotImplementedError:
>   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter does not support
>   changing column comments

Comment: using Rails 5.1.4

Comment: There's always `connection.execute('SQL to add the comment goes here')`.

Comment: Ah, that might be a pretty good solution I hadn't thought of. It would be nice to do it with more rails-y stuff, but I'll give that a shot for now.

Comment: `connection.execute("ALTER TABLE 'table_name' CHANGE 'id' 'id' BIGINT(20) COMMENT 'ID'  ")` gave the same error as the change_column function. I assume mysql2 may be the limiting factor here, unless rails has a clever solution to it.

Comment: A bit of googling suggests that the limitation is within MySQL itself. I think you might have to drop all the FKs, add the comment (which might be quite expensive), and then put the FKs back.

Comment: Dang, that does not sound fun. If that is the case I will probably resort to leaving off comments on them as most are just something like 'ID' anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign keys is still an issue, but I've managed to get a reasonable result by extracting the current data types and using them in the following statement structure for each column.

```
connection.execute("ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY `id` bigint(20) comment 'ID'")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message too:

> NotImplementedError: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter does not support changing column comments

When it occurs , you can change:

From:

```
    def change
change_column :tablename, :id, :bigint, comment: "id"
```

To:

```
    def up
change_column :tablename, :id, :bigint, comment: "id"
    end
    def down
change_column :tablename, :id, :bigint, comment: ""
    end
```

My Rails version: 5.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I dont get you, but why didn't you use [add_column](https://railsguide.org/rails/ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::SchemaStatements/add_column) instead of [change_column](https://railsguide.org/rails/ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter/change_column)

```
add_column :tablename, :comment, :text, default: "ID"
```

Comment: Because I'm making changes to an existing database. Unless add_column simply overwrites? I feel like it will throw an error that it already exists. But I suppose I haven't given it a shot, so I'll see how it interacts with this circumstance, but I get the feeling it won't solve either of the issues at hand.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, adding a separate comments column. To keep things consistent I need to use sql comments for this, also don't want to have the column returned on normal select * calls to it and such. Also it wouldn't result in the comments on the column itself.

Comment: To clarify, I want to add a comment to the column. Not add a comments column.